# Dropdown is not changing value on onChanged

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dropdown

I am fetching my firestore data and showing it in a dropdown list but in that list when i click on any item then the value or we can say hint text of dropdown doesn't change.

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(stream: compDoc.snapshots(),builder: (context, snapshot) {String? selectedValue;if (snapshot.hasError) {return Center(child: Text("Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}"),);}List<DropdownMenuItem> compItems = [];if (!snapshot.hasData) {return const CircularProgressIndicator();} else {final selectComp = snapshot.data?.docs.toList();if (selectComp != null) {`

`    for (var comp in selectComp) {
      compItems.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: comp['name'],
          child: Text(
            comp['name'],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton(
        underline: const SizedBox(),
        isExpanded: true,
        hint: Text(
          "Select items",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        value: selectedValue,
        items: compItems,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = value;
            print(selectedValue);
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Kindly someone help me.. i am stuck with that thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you put `selectedValue` inside the `builder` callback of the `StreamBuilder`. Move `selectedValue` to the `State` of the widget that wraps this `StreamBuilder`. For example:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return the StreamBuilder widget here
    // (or the widget that has that StreamBuilder somewhere in the widget tree)
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        String? selectedValue; // REMOVE this line
        // ...
      },
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

You can see an example usage of `setState` with dropdown in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Comment: Yea, i figured it out just after posting question.. haha